# User input other than print prompt and scanner

Tags: java, user-input

I wrote a program that asks for user input like this:

```
System.out.println("Where would you like the output file to end up? (full path and desired file name): ");
Scanner out_loc = new Scanner(System.in);
output_loc = out_loc.nextLine();
```

...

```
System.out.println("Hey, please write the full path of input file number " + i + "! ");
System.out.println("For example: /home/Stephanie/filein.txt");
Scanner fIn = new Scanner(System.in);
```

I ask several times for input in this way but it can get to be a huge pain if you mistype because then you have to kill the program and rerun. Is there an easy way to just take input all at once when you run a program? As in just declaring it in the command line when having it run?

```
java -jar /home/Stephanie/NetBeansProjects/cBelow/dist/cBelow.jar -userinputhere?
```

Comment: (or) You may have a file and use Scanner to read the file

Comment: That's the point of the args in the main method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the command as :

> java -jar /home/Stephanie/NetBeansProjects/cBelow/dist/cBelow.jar -userinputhere?

It runs the `public static void main(String[] args)` method of your primary class where you can get the `userinputhere` directly as:

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
     String userinputhere = args[0];
     ..... rest of your code
   }
```

If there are multiple user Inputs, you can get them all as :

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
      String userinput1 = args[0];
      String userinput2 = args[1];
      String userinput3 = args[2];
      //and so on..
      ..... rest of your code
  }
```

Comment: So in this case for each userinput (userinput1, userinput2) they would specify on the command line? Like this: java -jar /home/Stephanie/NetBeansProjects/cBelow/dist/cBelow.jar -userinput1 -userinput2 -userinput3     ?

Comment: @User: Yes. all inputs in command line separated by `space` and no need to prefix by `-`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use file redirection.

```
program < file
```

sends the file to the standard input of the program. In your case,

java -jar /home/Stephanie/NetBeansProjects/cBelow/dist/cBelow.jar -userinputhere < file

Or you can read from a file in your program.  You can make this optional like

```
InputStream in = args.length < 1 ? System.in : new FileInputStream(args[0]);
Scanner scan = new Scanner(in); // create the scanner just once!
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand. Could you explain a little further? I think my point of confusion is whether or not I am putting in each file name in the command line directly or making a file of file locations and passing that to the program.

Comment: You can redirect input from a file or give filenames to load or give a directory of files to load or give it a file listing filenames to load. Its up to you. I would do what you think is simplest.